# "Once you have days that are 118, 99 feels amazing."

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

This is from a podcast conversation.

Aubrey and Lindsay seem to talk about the weather:

> Aubrey: It might start cooling off eventually and I cannot wait.
>
> Lindsay: "Cooling off" said by Aubrey, which means going down to 99.
>
> **Aubrey: 90's exactly. I will take 99. Once you have days that are
> 118, 99 feels amazing.**

I can't understand what Aubrey said in the part in bold.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: These are Fahrenheit (American) temperatures. 99 degrees F may seem hot most times but if you have had days at 118 degrees F then 99 feels cool. 99 degrees F is 37 normal degrees, and 118 F is 47 normal folks degrees.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

> These are Fahrenheit (American) temperatures. 99 degrees F may seem hot most times but if you have had days at 118 degrees F then 99 feels cool. 99 degrees F is 37 normal degrees, and 118 F is 47 normal folks degrees. - @[MichaelHarvey](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/46805/michael-harvey)

To add on, this "amazing" reveals how cool 99 degrees F would seem to a person after experiencing such a hot weather beforehand. This explains the "cooling off" mentioned by Aubrey.